# Unable to debug .cu C++ code after upgrading from CUDA 10.2 to CUDA 11.5

Tags: debugging, cuda, visual-studio-2017

After upgrading from CUDA 10.2 to CUDA 11.5 I am unable to debug CUDA C++ code compiled in release, while CUDA C++ code compiled in debug can still be debugged.
I am using the integration of CUDA development in VS 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found the problem:
New version of CUDA VisualStudio integration adds the new property "Debug Information Format" that didn't exist in version 10.2
This new property must be set to "Program Database" that adds the /Zi switch
In the file "CUDA 10.2.props", this switch was set fixed for both debug and release configurations.

Comment: Please don't forget to [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and thanks for sharing the solution. Have a nice day :)